# Responsive Image for different screen resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation-5

Zurb Foundation comes with data inchange library which automatically selects the correct image size depending on screen resolution, which is great. When you change the browser window size, the image is automatically scaled up/down.

I've seen sites (like http://riotdesign.eu/en/ for example, even zurb foundation website itself) where when you change the width of the browser window, the image does not lose its height. I'm struggling to achieve this effect. Are there libraries people are using to achieve this, or its some special css setting?

Comment: Have you tried anything in that direction? Maybe use pre-scaled images for certain resolutions and play with media queries, thats entirely a CSS solution?

Comment: the data-interchange library does make use of media queries as far as i know; i've defined three sets of images for three different resolution, but as mentioned above, changing width also decreases the height.

Comment: I think that might be "worked arround" by setting background image position so that the central part of the image is always in the middle of the page. The cons is the image will be larger, but the visible part is being adjusted by the css